# Une œuvre télévisuelle, « portée » par quelqu'un ?

Tags: sens, verbes

> C’est un record pour une série française : « Lupin », **portée** par
> Omar Sy sur Netflix, est en passe d’être regardée par près de 70
> millions de foyers dans le monde, selon une projection réalisée par la
> plateforme et rendue publique ce mardi 19 janvier. ([AFP](https://www.nouvelobs.com/teleobs/20210119.OBS39046/lupin-avec-omar-sy-cartonne-sur-netflix-et-bat-tous-les-records-pour-une-serie-francaise.html))

De quel sens du verbe [*porter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/port%C3%A9) s'agit-il ici ?

Comment: I would say it is used in figurative style meaning Élever. See (13) here: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/porter#:~:text=Soutenir%20quelque%20chose%20ou%20quelqu,des%20vivres%20pour%20six%20mois.

Answer (score 4):

L'entrée *porter* est bien longue, difficile d'y trouver exactement ce sens.

Le plus proche est *porter quelque chose sur ses épaules*, dans le sens de supporter, avoir la responsabilité, être l'élément moteur ici du succès d'une œuvre.

> − [Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne une entité concr. ou abstr.; souvent avec compl. prép. désignant une partie du corps] *Ici, j'ai le sentiment de porter tous les musées sur mes épaules* (Larbaud, *Barnabooth*, 1913, p.202).
> [Avec une idée de responsabilité] *Porter les certitudes de qqn, le destin d'un pays. Quant à M. Geoffroy, il portait toute la pièce sur ses larges épaules, avec l'aisance et la bonhomie d'un grand artiste* (Zola, *Bouton de rose*, 1878, p.vi). *C'est une idée qu'il faut porter à bras, car elle est souvent démentie et toujours menacée* (Alain, *Propos*, 1931, p.1018). *[L'acteur] peut porter les espoirs ou les doutes de tout un peuple, mais il est seul à assumer son propre destin* (Serrière, T.N.P., 1959, p.143).

On retrouve aussi un peu le sens de porter en soi:

> − [Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne un produit de l'esprit dont la mise au point nécessite du temps] *Porter un livre, un sujet. Jamais personne ne se douta de mon projet, bien que je l'aie porté quatre ans dans mon cœur avec toutes les émotions de la crainte et de l'espérance* (Sand, Hist. vie, t.2, 1855, p.426). *Je flânerais, je porterais bien plus longtemps mes romans en moi, et ils seraient meilleurs* (Green, Journal, 1932, p.104). *Sans doute ai-je obéi d'instinct à l'exigence de l'oeuvre que je portais* (Mauriac, Bloc-Notes, 1958, p.89).

Comment: Effectivement je pense aussi que c'est cela que ca signifie... On peut raisonnablement estimer que si il n'y avait pas Omar Sy cette série n'aurait pas ce succès. Cela dit ca peut aussi vouloir dire qu'il soutient la série autrement que par sa présence, par exemple en la produisant en partie.

Comment: Est-ce qu'on aurait pu vouloir dire _porter le rôle de_ Lupin et on se serait trompé de genre ou on aurait mélangé deux sens ? Est-ce qu'on voulait dire _à bout de bras_ ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Est-ce qu'on pourrait avoir voulu dire : _adapter pour Netflix_ une oeuvre existante ?

Comment: 1. Le rôle de Lupin porté par Omar Sy: peu vraisemblable. 2. Porté à bout de bras: plus proche du sens, mais contradictoire avec le reste du texte. On porte plutôt à bout de bras quelque chose ou quelqu'un qui ne va pas bien. 3. Porté sur Netflix. C'est du vocabulaire d'informaticien (une appli iPhone portée sur Android).

Comment: D'accord, merci. Donc aucune idée de distribution des rôles là-dedans... Que penses-tu alors d'un emploi métonymique pour la performance qui transporte l'oeuvre, voire qui la transcende ? cc @dimitris

Comment: Oui, ce n'est pas loin de mon *élément moteur du succès de l’œuvre*.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. I would say it is used in figurative style meaning Élever. See the sense (13) here: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/porter#Verbe

Comment: Maybe, yet all the examples use _dans_ + something whereas there is none of that here. Which doesn't mean that it wouldn't be that. Just noticed at first glance.